# What is the best solvent for Mutagen X?

Tags: biochemistry, cancer, toxicology, lab-reagents, materials

Many solvents can be used for mutagen X (3-chloro-4-(dichloromethyl)-5-hydroxy-5H-furan-2-one), however, long-term stability is not specified. Which would be the best solvent for long-term storage? Once dissolved, can it be stored at RT or -20ºC?

Thanks